SQL Divide two calculated columns
I have a dynamic query that is joining several tables. Two columns are getting the sum of values from the query while the third wants to divide those two values to get a percentage. Currently, I have the query working and it is written similar to this:
select
   SUM(CASE when (t2.col1 = 'Eligible' and t2.col2 != 'Exempt') then 1 else 0 end) as 'CalculatedCol1'
   ,SUM(case when t2.col1 = 'Eligible' and t2.col2 != 'Exempt' and (t2.Date1 < t2.Date2) then 1 else 0 end) as 'CalcualtedCol2'
   ,SUM(CASE when (t2.col1 = 'Eligible' and t2.col2 != 'Exempt') then 1 else 0 end) / SUM(case when t2.col1 = 'Eligible' and t2.col2 != 'Exempt' and (t2.Date1 < t2.Date2) then 1 else 0 end) as 'Division'
from
   t1
   left join t2 on t2.fk = t1.pk
where
   blah blah blah

What I would like to do is not have to run the SUM statement for the two CalculatedColumns again just to divide them but instead say CalculatedCol1 / CalculatedCol2 as 'Division'.
I know I can achieve this if I were to seperate this into 2 seperate statements and build the Calcualted columns to a temp table or using a WITH, but I unfortunately cannot rebuild the dynamic query to support that at the moment. Is there a way I could achieve this in a single select statement?

Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server? (You can remove the other tag.)

Do the first two in a derived table (or cte), then do the divide using its result.

You can wrap the above in a subquery, like: select a, b, a / (1.0 * b) from (<your query>) x Note that you're kinda playing fast and loose with LEFT JOINs and NULLs, i'm 99% sure your results are wrong, but that's neither here nor there

I've gone ahead and removed the conflicting tags; please [edit] your question to (re)tag the actual (R)DBMS you are using. Why does tagging multiple RDBMS products make my question unclear?

I would use a CTE

try the following:
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT
        SUM(CASE WHEN (t2.col1 = 'Eligible' AND t2.col2 != 'Exempt') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS CalculatedCol1,
        SUM(CASE WHEN t2.col1 = 'Eligible' AND t2.col2 != 'Exempt' AND (t2.Date1 < t2.Date2) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS CalculatedCol2
    FROM
        t1
        LEFT JOIN t2 ON t2.fk = t1.pk
    WHERE <filter-conditions>
)
SELECT
    CalculatedCol1,
    CalculatedCol2,
    CASE 
        WHEN CalculatedCol2 != 0 THEN CalculatedCol1 / CalculatedCol2
        ELSE 0  -- case to handle division by zero
    END AS Division
FROM
    cte;


Hey DataWizard. Thanks for the reply, but unfortunately becuase of the dynamic nature of the query, I cannot add TMP tables or a WITH statement easily without making upstream changes.
I was hoping I could find a way of doing this inside a single select statement.
